# Encounter error when I import MediaPlayer in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Normally I don't have a problem with following code and works properly. But, to add a video, I import MediaPlayer under the UIKit and right after that encounter following error : "Ambiguous use of stringValue" on second line in second exclamation mark.

Do you have any idea why this is happening ?

```
let replyID1 = (friendObj["reply"])

let aString = replyID1!!.stringValue

self.sharedReplyResults.append(aString )
```

Answer (score 0):

It solved as follows :

```
let replyID1 = (friendObj["reply"])

let aString = replyID1??.stringValue

self.sharedReplyResults.append(aString! )
```